# After switching from jquery-ui 1.8.x to 1.10.3, "tabs()" do not work as expected....--Is there a workaround to enable the "tab key" work again?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

After switching from jquery-ui 1.8.x to 1.10.3,  "tabs()" do not work as expected....

**Question:**  Is there a workaround to enable the "tab key" work again?

Notes:

The user formerly was able to use the "tab key" to move thru each tab/panel.
--This no longer works, and has become a bit of a "508 compliance" issue.

*(Note: this app does not use a `<base>` url tag.)*

## UPDATE:

So, it turns out that "tab" key is tabbing, but, because, for whatever reason the focused tab is no longer detectable (or, highlighted/outlined).  This makes it appear as if it is not working.

*(would this be due to CSS change when switching to the new version of jQuery-ui) ?*

I've tried various css entries to gain control...

The only one that appears to have an effect is this selector:

```
    .ui-widget :focus     
    { 
        border-style: inset !important;
        border-width: 5px !important;
    }
```

However this selector too broad and impacts other widgets.  I only want to "highlight" the focused tab  -  not other elements.

So, how can I select, and effect change (on focus) to the "tabs" only?
(did the "tab"-related class names change in the new jquery-ui version, I wonder...)

Perhaps - since this is a different question, I should create a new post?

Comment: Seems like you can tab to the tab group and then use the arrow keys to navigate amongst the tabs. Does that not work for you?

Comment: Fiddle me this, Batman

Comment: You're going to have to do some compliance of your own -- SO compliance. Tell us what "do not work as expected" really means please.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit try it on the jQuery UI demo. pressing tab does not navigate between the tabs.

Comment: Yes, j08691 - I found that this was the case. However, the tabs no longer "highlight" to indicate that they are focused and/or active when tabbing thru them (with the "tab" key).  I'm not certain why this is the case.  -And, thx for viewing/posting comments.

Comment: @KevinB: I'm looking for the OP to expand his question beyond "it doesn't work". The update is much better.

Comment: It appears that the tabbing behavior has changed after upgrading from jquery-ui 1.8.x to 1.10.x.... As j08691 and Kevin B have indicated.....Previously, pressing tab would move control between tabs. But, since upgrading, pressing tab only moves to the tab panel. Thereafter, the user must use the "arrow" keys to move between tabs. (I assume this change was made to adhere to a new "standard" - unfortunately when upgrading it breaks existing behavior).  Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the full URL of the site in the hash links.
Here's an example:

```php
<div id="loginTabs">    
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li><a href="<?php echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; ?>#parent-login">Parent Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; ?>#staff-login">Staff Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; ?>#student-login">Student Login</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="parent-login">
        <?php $this->showLoginForm("parent"); ?>
    </div>

    <div id="student-login">
        <?php $this->showLoginForm("student"); ?>
    </div>

    <div id="staff-login">
        <?php $this->showLoginForm("staff"); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'll recommend you use version 1.8.x for your project, since it doesn't have this issue.